# Cookie - addClass if user has already clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I have a list of links, I would like to add a class when the user has already clicked that link to give it some styling, so they know that they have already viewed this link. I am using the cookies.js plugin to help achieve this.

An example of the JSFiddle is here:- http://jsfiddle.net/kjhdbnfe/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = Cookies.get('active');
    $(".clearfix").find('a').eq(index).addClass('active');
    $('.clearfix').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        Cookies.set('active', $('.clearfix a').index(this));
    });
});
```

```css
nav li a.active
{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fd9625;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Cookies.js/0.3.1/cookies.js"></script>
<nav>
<!-- nav menu -->
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a runat="server" href="Slideshow.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why not use `a:visited`?

Comment: @MrKhan on refresh, it is not remembering all the clicked links, it seems to be removing some

Comment: When setting the cookie you will override the index of the previous clicked link with the currently clicked link. To make sure to grab all clicked links, stringify an array an manipluate that on click or something like that. Remember to have add clean up mechanism/ expiration date.

Comment: I made you a snippet. You need to always use the HTTPS versions - alas the script does not run as a snippet due to sandboxing

Comment: Why not use sessionStorage or localStorage? Cookies are only needed when you need to share the cookie with the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each time you click on a Link, you override the previous click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".clearfix a").each(function () {
    if (Cookies.get($(this).attr("data-link"))) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

  $('.clearfix').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    Cookies.set('link-' + $('.clearfix a').index(this), 'active');
  });
});

<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a runat="server" data-link="link-0" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" data-link="link-2" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" data-link="link-1" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 <ul>

 a.active {
    color:red !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `visited` CSS selector for that, try my example, [more information](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp):

```css
a:visited {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li><a runat="server" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a runat="server" href="#About">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a runat="server" href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not required for this. You can do this with local storage. Add data attribute to give it a unique identifier and one we will use for classes as well.

**HTML FILE:**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#" data-id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="about_us">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a  href="#" data-id="contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>  
</nav>
```

Next, in your jquery on click simply fetch the data attribute value and pass it to the local storage and add it as a class as well because its the name of our class.

**JS FILE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.clearfix > li a').on('click', function (e) {
        let link = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
            localStorage.setItem(link,link);
        $(this).addClass(link);
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.home{
    color:orange;
}
.about_us{
    color:orange;
}

.contact_us{

    color:orange;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample</title>
<style>
    nav li a.active{
        background: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
      <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
             <a runat="server" id="one" href="#" onclick="changeColor('one')">Home</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
             <a runat="server" id="two" href="#" onclick="changeColor('two')">About 
             Us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a runat="server" id="three" href="#" 
             onclick="changeColor('three')">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
 <script>
        function changeColor(id){
            if (document.querySelector(`#${id}`).style.background === "red"){
                document.querySelector(`#${id}`).style.background = "white";
                // document.querySelector(this).style.background === "white";
            }else{
                // document.querySelector(this).style.background === "red";
                document.querySelector(`#${id}`).style.background = "red";
            }
        }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```